# Insert user who posts

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am making up a form php/mysql. The form is adding data to database. One part of the form is adding the user who adds the data. Rather than it be a select box where they can choose any username.

I need the this form part to show them their username not select of the whole list.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="users" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select User: <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="post_user" class="form-control" id="">

           <?php

                $users_query = "SELECT username FROM users";
                $select_users = mysqli_query($connection,$users_query);

                confirmQuery($select_users);


                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_users)) {
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $username = $row['username'];

            echo "<option value='{$username}'>{$username}</option>";

            }
          ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i could not understand what you want to do. Will you please explain??

Comment: It is a form that sends data to the database. one of the fields in the form must show the users their username. A disabled input that will show them their username

Comment: Where is your question!?

Comment: nice. now would you love to describe table fields of database??
just add a snapshot if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well assuming each username is unique, all you need to do is get the person's username (whether that is from a cookie or otherwise) and use a 
[Prepared Statement.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) Using the prepared statement will allow you to input different names into your SQL query.

Your echo seems to incorrect. The simplest way is to split the echo into parts like any other language and concatenate it.

So from your code, your echo needs to be like so:

```
echo "<option value='". $username ."'>" . $username . "</option>";
```

Comment: the echo is fine - variables can be used inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Select2 jquery plugin](https://select2.github.io).

> Select2 gives you a customizable select box with support for
>   searching, tagging, remote data sets, infinite scrolling, and many
>   other highly used options.

You can disable options in your selectbox and just show it.

```
<select class="js-example-disabled-results"> 
<option value="one">First</option>
<option value="two" disabled="disabled">Second (disabled)</option> 
<option value="three">Third</option>
 </select>
```

See [examples page of select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out. Should help. Please note -: $username and $password are just for reference. Best Practise is to make them secure.

```
<?php

     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = "stackoverflow";

     // Create connection
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         echo "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
     }else
     {
         echo "Connection success<br>";
     }

     $sql = "select * from users";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     echo "<select>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $user = $row['username'];
         echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
?>
```